# VPN client sees NAS but not printer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, printer, openvpn

I connected my co-worker via Open VPN to our work network.
The main reason for this is that my co-worker can connect to our NAS. That is working.
In the past she also could print in our office from home, but that's not possible anymore.

That could be because I changed some VPN config settings to not rout everything (all traffic) through the VPN to not slowdown both networks.

Also when I check the router, the "co-worker pc" doesn't appear in the network.

These are my main configs for the VPN I installed on her computer:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
nobind
pull
resolv-retry infinite
key-direction 1



// The following are not at the top and distributed through the config, I'm not sure what they are doing, but I put them here so you can maybe spot the error.

proto udp
script-security 2
comp-lzo
reneg-sec 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-user-pass
```

My question is now:

How is it possible that she can connect to the NAS, but not to the printer?
And what option do I have to change the connect to the printer again, without routing everything. Is that even possible?

Comment: Is the Printer connected via DHCP? It may have gotten lost. Configure the Printer for Static IP so it has the same IP address all the time. That will most likely fix the issue.  The NAS will be on a static IP.

Comment: @John Yes, the NAS has a static IP. I will give the printer also a static ip. But I'm still wondering why she doesn't appear in the router (shown in the network as she would when she is here).

Comment: I am not entirely sure. What I have to do occasionally is turn off the printer, disconnect the Ethernet, start the printer and connect the Ethernet during startup. Also see if there is a firmware update for your printer.